# Как убрать белый шум в наушниках на ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, аудио

При подключение наушников белый шум .

> sudo aplay -l
>   **** Список PLAYBACK устройств ****
>   карта 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], устройство 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
>     Подустройства: 1/1
>     Подустройство №0: subdevice #0
>   карта 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], устройство 0: ALC3227 Analog [ALC3227 Analog]
>     Подустройства: 1/1
>     Подустройство №0: subdevice #0

Пробовал метод из данного [источника](http://ubuntu.fliplinux.com/x43-73.html).

> Перемещение по loopback (все вправо, с помощью клавиши → ) и установка его на значение Disabled с помощью клавиши ↑ .

Шум стал тише ,но не исчез полностью.

Редактировал файл поставил  `INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false`.

У микрофона в настройках тоже поставил мут .

Comment: А почему вы решили, что к шуму имеет отношение ubuntu? В других операционных системах шума нет или как?

Comment: @andreymal в windows 7 такого не было.

Comment: А если в windows 7 запустить на воспроизведение файл с тишиной?

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, вспомнил, что тут спрашивали. Белый шум без звука. Перезагрузка не решила проблему. Решилось так: параметры звука > "воспроизведение звука через", переставил на цифровой выход, затем назад вернул на аналоговый выход.